# React Component - Why can dispatch in AsyncApp Components

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

Refer to this example
https://redux.js.org/advanced/example-reddit-api

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {
  selectSubreddit,
  fetchPostsIfNeeded,
  invalidateSubreddit
} from '../actions'
import Picker from '../components/Picker'
import Posts from '../components/Posts'

class AsyncApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleRefreshClick = this.handleRefreshClick.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { dispatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props
    dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(selectedSubreddit))
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.selectedSubreddit !== prevProps.selectedSubreddit) {
      const { dispatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props
      dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(selectedSubreddit))
    }
  }

  handleChange(nextSubreddit) {
    this.props.dispatch(selectSubreddit(nextSubreddit))
    this.props.dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(nextSubreddit))
  }

  handleRefreshClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const { dispatch, selectedSubreddit } = this.props
    dispatch(invalidateSubreddit(selectedSubreddit))
    dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(selectedSubreddit))
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedSubreddit, posts, isFetching, lastUpdated } = this.props
    return (
      <div>
        <Picker
          value={selectedSubreddit}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          options={['reactjs', 'frontend']}
        />
        <p>
          {lastUpdated && (
            <span>
              Last updated at {new Date(lastUpdated).toLocaleTimeString()}.{' '}
            </span>
          )}
          {!isFetching && (
            <button onClick={this.handleRefreshClick}>Refresh</button>
          )}
        </p>
        {isFetching && posts.length === 0 && <h2>Loading...</h2>}
        {!isFetching && posts.length === 0 && <h2>Empty.</h2>}
        {posts.length > 0 && (
          <div style={{ opacity: isFetching ? 0.5 : 1 }}>
            <Posts posts={posts} />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

AsyncApp.propTypes = {
  selectedSubreddit: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  isFetching: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  lastUpdated: PropTypes.number,
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const { selectedSubreddit, postsBySubreddit } = state
  const { isFetching, lastUpdated, items: posts } = postsBySubreddit[
    selectedSubreddit
  ] || {
    isFetching: true,
    items: []
  }

  return {
    selectedSubreddit,
    posts,
    isFetching,
    lastUpdated
  }
}
```

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AsyncApp)

The function can trigger the actions like 'fetchPostsIfNeeded' with     this.props.dispatch(fetchPostsIfNeeded(nextSubreddit)). However, it supposes relate to mapDispatchToProps. So may i know the scenario why the program run succeeds with no error

Comment: connect passes dispatch if you don't pass second parameter to connect, please refer - https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#mapdispatchtoprops-object-dispatch-ownprops-object

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

Actually, `connect()` has provided the dispatch to your component already.(https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#example-usage)

You can take `mapDispatchToProps` as a middleware for creating methods with dispatch.

Lets say we have a store with state counter.

```
{
    counter: 0
}
```

in `mapDispatchToProps`, we can create methods using in this component :

```
{
 increment: ()=>{dispatch({ type: 'EDIT', payload: 1 })},
 decrement: ()=>{dispatch({ type: 'EDIT', payload: -1 })}
}
```